# JQuery.post gets cookies from server but not settings them on my computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, cookies

I'm using JQuery.post in order to login into an API, the POST request works but the cookie that is being sent back from the server isn't being set on my computer.

Does anyone knows a way to set the cookie that was retrieved from the server?

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can set a cookie this way:

```
document.cookie="name=value";
```

So you can parse the response from the server and set the cookie.